# Why do I get an error in result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, alpha_mask)?

Tags: python, opencv

When running the program, it gives an error

`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:214: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::binary_op'.`

my code

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2
import numpy as np

def create_watermark_mask(image_file, output_file):
    image = Image.open(image_file)
    mask = Image.new('L', image.size, 0)
    mask.paste(255, mask=image.convert('L'))
    mask.save(output_file)

def remove_watermark(image_file, mask_file, output_file):

    image = cv2.imread(image_file)
    mask = cv2.imread(mask_file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    blurred_mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (5, 5), 0)
    _, binary_mask = cv2.threshold(blurred_mask, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    alpha_mask = cv2.cvtColor(binary_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA)
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, alpha_mask)
    cv2.imwrite(output_file, result)



image_file = 'I:\python\lpo\images\cf.jpg' 
mask_file = 'I:\python\lpo\images\heko.png'  
output_file = 'I:\python\lpo\images\iwo.png'  

create_watermark_mask(image_file, mask_file)


remove_watermark(image_file, mask_file, output_file)
```

i cheked sizes of images and all be true. idk what can be it

Comment: `image = cv2.imread(image_file)` -- by default, the second parameter is `IMREAD_COLOR`, so `image` has 3 channels. On the other hand `alpha_mask = cv2.cvtColor(binary_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA)`, so `alpha_mask` has 4 channels. Therefore, in the call `cv2.bitwise_and(image, alpha_mask)` the two arguments have different size, and your claim that "cheked sizes of images and all be true." is simply untrue.

Comment: oh, sorry, i small think about cv4. Thank, i try fix

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bitwise\_and sizes of input arguments do not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664539/bitwise-and-sizes-of-input-arguments-do-not-match)